# PHP imagecreatefromjpeg no error, no image

Tags: php, jpeg, gd

I am using this code

```
<?php

$sImagePath = $_GET["file"];

$iThumbnailWidth = (int)$_GET['width'];
$iThumbnailHeight = (int)$_GET['height'];
$iMaxWidth = (int)$_GET["maxw"];
$iMaxHeight = (int)$_GET["maxh"];

if ($iMaxWidth && $iMaxHeight) $sType = 'scale';
else if ($iThumbnailWidth && $iThumbnailHeight) $sType = 'exact';

$img = NULL;

$sExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $sImagePath)));
if ($sExtension == 'jpg' || $sExtension == 'jpeg') {

    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($sImagePath)
        or die("Cannot create new JPEG image");

} else if ($sExtension == 'png') {

    $img = @imagecreatefrompng($sImagePath)
        or die("Cannot create new PNG image");

} else if ($sExtension == 'gif') {

    $img = @imagecreatefromgif($sImagePath)
        or die("Cannot create new GIF image");

}

if ($img) {

    $iOrigWidth = imagesx($img);
    $iOrigHeight = imagesy($img);

    if ($sType == 'scale') {

        // Get scale ratio

        $fScale = min($iMaxWidth/$iOrigWidth,
              $iMaxHeight/$iOrigHeight);

        if ($fScale < 1) {

            $iNewWidth = floor($fScale*$iOrigWidth);
            $iNewHeight = floor($fScale*$iOrigHeight);

            $tmpimg = imagecreatetruecolor($iNewWidth,
                               $iNewHeight);

            imagecopyresampled($tmpimg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            $iNewWidth, $iNewHeight, $iOrigWidth, $iOrigHeight);

            imagedestroy($img);
            $img = $tmpimg;
        }     

    } else if ($sType == "exact") {

        $fScale = max($iThumbnailWidth/$iOrigWidth,
              $iThumbnailHeight/$iOrigHeight);

        if ($fScale < 1) {

            $iNewWidth = floor($fScale*$iOrigWidth);
            $iNewHeight = floor($fScale*$iOrigHeight);

            $tmpimg = imagecreatetruecolor($iNewWidth,
                            $iNewHeight);
            $tmp2img = imagecreatetruecolor($iThumbnailWidth,
                            $iThumbnailHeight);

            imagecopyresampled($tmpimg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            $iNewWidth, $iNewHeight, $iOrigWidth, $iOrigHeight);

            if ($iNewWidth == $iThumbnailWidth) {

                $yAxis = ($iNewHeight/2)-
                    ($iThumbnailHeight/2);
                $xAxis = 0;

            } else if ($iNewHeight == $iThumbnailHeight)  {

                $yAxis = 0;
                $xAxis = ($iNewWidth/2)-
                    ($iThumbnailWidth/2);

            } 

            imagecopyresampled($tmp2img, $tmpimg, 0, 0,
                       $xAxis, $yAxis,
                       $iThumbnailWidth,
                       $iThumbnailHeight,
                       $iThumbnailWidth,
                       $iThumbnailHeight);

            imagedestroy($img);
            imagedestroy($tmpimg);
            $img = $tmp2img;
        }    

    }

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($img);

}

?>
```

and the imagecreatefromjpeg works on eight of my images but not on three of them. They are Photoshop "save for web jpgs" with good permissions. I am not getting an error, but I am also not getting a "true" on line 33 "if($img)"

Comment: Have you check their extension correctly?

Comment: If error reporting and display are off on your server, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: What I'm suspecting is that it's because you only have a single type of header `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` which won't work for `.png` and `.gif`. You will need to try and add the appropriate headers inside another set of conditionals. That's if the ones related to those other files with types other than `jpeg`.

Comment: Fred -ii- ; thanks for the reply.  I only get two notices from code lines 5&6...
Notice: Undefined index: width in (url)
Notice: Undefined index: height in (url)

Comment: You're welcome. Then, it's how you're passing the URL with the GET method. You'll need to show us an example of how you're using it.

Comment: all of my images are jpgs. 8 jpgs work, 3 don't.  I am just viewing the image in the browser at this point passing in variables in the url. The reason that it's giving those notices is that I am not including those variables in the url. Only including the variables I need (file,maxw,maxh)

Comment: in the browser address bar thmb.php?file=out/scot-nery-headshot2.jpg&maxw=300&maxh=500 ....... an example that works is thmb.php?file=out/scot-nery-headshot1.jpg&maxw=300&maxh=500

Comment: Maybe try also removing the error message suppression operator (`@`) just in case it's hiding some problem when opening the image.

Comment: Thank you, @outlyer ! I didn't understand the purpose of the "at" It was a memory cap issue.